# how to store or display extended report in eclips after refreshing projects and simultanously at mentioned drive

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Simultaneously, I want to display a extended report on eclipse window(which is come after refreshing project)and mentioned driver(eg. d:/project name/...) using selenium webdriver

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want and what you tried for this

Comment: I want to display extended report on eclips window which is come after refreshing our project. Also I want same (extended report) on drive which is mentioned in code. I want to display same extended report on both eclipse window  and mentioned driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Extend report @BeforeTest method

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUp1() {
    // where we need to generate the report
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:/xampp/htdocs/Automation_report/files/summerrentals/summerrentals("+fileName+").html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    // Set our document title, theme etc..
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Testing");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Testing");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
}
```

Its after Medhod for attached screenshot

```
@AfterMethod
    public void setTestResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {

        String screenShot = CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(wd, CaptureScreenShot.generateFileName(result));

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.log(Status.FAIL, result.getName());
            test.log(Status.FAIL,result.getThrowable());
            test.fail("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            test.log(Status.PASS, result.getName());
            test.pass("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            test.skip("Test Case : " + result.getName() + " has been skipped");
        }

        extent.flush();
        wd.quit();
    }
```

This is my CaptureScreenShot  class for taking screenshot

```
 public class CaptureScreenShot {
                private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd SSS");

                public static String captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String screenName) throws IOException{

                    TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                    File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

                    String dest ="C:/xampp//htdocs/Automation_report/Test-ScreenShots"+screenName+".png";

                    File target = new File(dest);
                    FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);

                    return dest;
                }

                public static String generateFileName(ITestResult result){
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String fileName = result.getName()+ "_" + dateFormat.format(date);
                    return fileName;

                }
            }
```

> Hope It will help you

Answer (score 0):

May be you want the report to be created in the drive/folder d:/project name/...

```
     // start reporters
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("d://testproject/extent.html");

    // create ExtentReports and attach reporter(s)
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

This will create the extent report in the folder/drive `d://testproject`. I have assumed the project name is testproject here.